# What is the string for Menu key in X keysyms?

Tags: keyboard, xdotool

I'm trying to simulate `Menu` key press using `xdotool` but I'm unable to find the proper string for the key.

There is a list of X keysyms in [here](https://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/List_of_keysyms) but `Menu` (or `Application`) key is not in the list. I'm currently using `click 3` but there's a slight difference between mouse right click and `Menu` key.

Comment: You can use `xev` command for that.

Comment: @AkashKarnatak Interesting thing is the keysym is `Menu` but xdotool does not type it since it's not present in my keyboard.

Comment: What' a menu key? Are you referring to Windows(or Super) key?

Comment: @AkashKarnatak No, it's usually placed at the right side of space and opens context menu (right click menu).

Comment: You can emulate menu key using `Shift+F10`